# Animating view width whilst using auto layout

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I am using auto layout to position a custom progress bar (its simply a UIView with a background colour).  Im not using a proper progress bar because I didnt want to have to fully customise it to my needs when a UIView will suffice.

Anyway I have told XCode to place the progress bar to the left, and a certain distance from the bottom.  This positions it correctly but when I animate the width nothing happens.  If I create a new UIVIew then animate that it works correctly.  Are the constraints preventing this from animating? No constrains is placed upon the width at all

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:startingGameSeconds delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^(void) {
                     progressBar.frame = CGRectMake(progressBar.frame.origin.x,
                                                    progressBar.frame.origin.y,
                                                    320,
                                                    progressBar.frame.size.height);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }];
```

Comment: Yes, constraints preventing this from animating. Even you don't have width constraint, you have leader and trailing constraints, am I right?

Comment: Animate the constraint :)

Comment: Yes I have leading and trailing constraint for left and bottom edge.

Comment: What constraints do you have in the horizontal direction? You either need to have 2 (one to left and one to right), or one and a fixed width.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're using Auto Layout you shouldn't be using the `setFrame:` method anymore. When you want to animate the 'frame', you'll have to animate the constraints. I suppose your Auto Layout constraints are defined in Interface Builder. First, make sure you have a width layout constraint added to your progress bar. Next, create an IBOutlet for this width layout constraint. You can now animate the constraint like this:

```
self.progressBarWidthLayoutConstraint.constant = 320;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: You can set the constant before calling animateWithDuration.