# How to hide UIPickerView on 'viewDidLoad'?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to hide my UIPickerView when my app is loaded. but later on it will show / hide when button tapped.

So, I decided to put this code on viewDidLoad :

```
UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
float pvHeight = pickerView.frame.size.height;
float y = _screen.bounds.size.height - (pvHeight * -2);
_memberList.frame = CGRectMake(0 , y, pickerView.frame.size.width, pvHeight);
```

but when I run my app, it still there on default position. how to initially hide UIPickerView when it's loaded for the first time?

even if I manipulates value of y it still doesn't change anything... it's seems that there's something wrong with the code...

thank you.

UPDATE : I have this code to animate (show/hide) the UIPickerView later on using button, so what I need is initial position to be outside the screen when user runs the app. not Alpha = 0.

```
UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init]; // default frame is set
    float pvHeight = pickerView.frame.size.height;
    float y = _screen.bounds.size.height - (pvHeight); // the root view of view controller
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        _memberList.frame = CGRectMake(0 , y, pickerView.frame.size.width, pvHeight);
    } completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
pickerView.hidden = YES;
```

and in action of tap show the UIPickerView.

```
pickerView.hidden = NO;
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: ooooppsss... it's seems that your method is just working for hiding the picker view for the first time, but when I try to show it using animation it's not showing, because I need to use pickerView.hidden = YES to showing. and it's not animated.

Comment: If you want to animate showing the view, you could use the `alpha` property.  
You can animate it from 0.f to 1.f to fade in the view.

Comment: @IvonneSiswanto : why you want to animate?

Comment: @FahimParkar : I want to make UIPickerView shows / hide just like iOS keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

into your `viewDidLoad` write:

```
[yourView setAlpha:0];
```

when button pressed and you want to make it visible write this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0. options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    [yourView setAlpha:1];
} completion:nil];
```

if you want to hide it again :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0. options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    [yourView setAlpha:0];
} completion:nil];
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but please check my update because I'm not using Alpha to animate it's appearance...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've enabled Auto Layout. If you're using Auto Layout, you shouldn't use the `setFrame` method anymore, since Auto Layout while automatically do this for you.
You need to set up a constraint, probably a top space constraint in your case, and set the `constant` property of that `UILayoutConstraint`. So in your `viewDidLoad`, you set the `constant` so your view is outside of the window's bounds. And when the button is tapped, you animate the `constant` to a value so the view appears inside the window's bounds.

Take a look at this question: [Animating view with Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764498/animating-view-width-whilst-using-auto-layout/18768561#18768561)